# US tax refund tax status in India

Tags: united-states, taxes, india

I am a Indian citizen and I was in the US for a year.

I have received tax refund cheques from US Treasury.

Since I am back in India, I have deposited these cheques in my Indian bank account.

Is the US tax refund received taxable in India ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is the US tax refund received taxable in India ?

As this was income when your status was NRI, this does not attract taxes in India. There is a 7 years period by which you can bring in the funds earned outside India [when you tax status is NRI] into India.